# Is it possible to get rgb values of main view in android?

Tags: android

I need toget rgb values of main view in android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUF6H.jpg)

It is my app menu. and the resolution of the display is 2560 x 1440.

I want to get rgb view of the pixels of the display.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version:** Yes, it is.

**Long version:** Yes, it is, but You need to be specific about which pixel You want to examine for rgb. If You want to just get color palette then use Palette library from Android - it will extract primary colors from specified view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I am going to try to use Palette library for my idea :)